# Anaconda Spyder Auto Complete DOES work, but it does not show the possible solutions

Tags: ide, anaconda, spyder

Sorry for another post like this, I found a LOT of them here asking how to enable auto-completion, but that is not my case.

If I declare a variable and then hit `CTRL+Space` it works - it will autocomplete it. What I am missing thought is, that is shows a list of the possible solutions while typing - how do I enable that? (They only show after hitting `CTRL+Space`, is there no feature like in IntelliJ where they show that during typing already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) I guess what you are referring to is auto-completion *on the fly*, i.e. as you write on the Editor or Console.

Unfortunately, it's not possible to enable that right now (August/2018). However, it'll be available (but only for the Editor) in our next major version: Spyder **4**, to be released in 2019.